# macro to count and give result

Tags: excel, excel-formula, vba

Can anyone help me.    I want to count how many of the numbers are > 45 and put the result 3 rows below the last data cell. Lets give it a name - call it result. Then to the left of result I would like to put the words Number > 45. The amount of data rows will change, so when I run the macro on column D it will find the last data point and do the calculation. Some of the rows will be empty. Thanks for the help

Its should like that this

```
     50          
     20

        100
    120
     45
     30
     30
```

Return >45=   4

```
Sub enter()
    Dim result As Integer
    Dim firstrow As Integer
    Dim lastwow As Integer
    Firstrow = d2 
    Result = ‘ Value of count
    Worksheets("sheet1").Range("c?").Value = "Total>45"
    Range("d100000").End(xlUp).Select
End Sub
```

Comment: >45 should be 3 and not 4 in your case :)

Comment: Has any of the answers answered your question? If so please help other users by marking it as the answer, see [about].

Answer (score 2):

Try this

```
Sub Sample()
    Dim result As Long, firstrow As Long, lastrow As Long
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Dim rng As Range

    '~~> Set this to the relevant worksheet
    Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1")

    With ws
        '~~> Find Lastrow in Col D
        lastrow = .Range("D" & .Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
        '~~> Set First row
        firstrow = 1

        '~~> Set your range
        Set rng = .Range("D" & firstrow & ":D" & lastrow)

        '~~> Put relevant values
        .Range("C" & lastrow + 3).Value = "Total>45"
        .Range("D" & lastrow + 3).Value = _
        Application.WorksheetFunction.CountIf(rng, ">45")

    End With
End Sub
```

**Screenshot**

[image]

Comment: Is there a reason behind why you set `firstrow = 1` when you could just do `Set rng = .Range("D1:D" & lastrow)` ? Or as the OP seems to want `Set rng = .Range("D2:D" & lastrow)`

Comment: Yes there is a reason :) And that is flexibility to change the row number. I can do it as you suggested but by habit, I always declare my variables in the beginning so that I don't have to change the code every where but just at one location.

Answer (score 1):

Here's one that will let you pass in any number, not just 45

```
Sub MakeCount(lGreaterThan As Long)

    Dim lLast As Long

    With Sheet1
        lLast = .Cells(.Rows.Count, 4).End(xlUp).Row
        .Cells(lLast + 3, 4).FormulaR1C1 = "=COUNTIF(R[-" & lLast + 1 & "]C:R[-3]C,"">""&RC[-1])"
        .Cells(lLast + 3, 3).Value = lGreaterThan
        .Cells(lLast + 3, 3).NumberFormat = """Number>""#"
    End With

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

can't you use a worksheet formula like

`=COUNTIF(A2:A7,">45")`

alternatively, in VBA as Mr **Siddharth Rout** suggests in his answer

Comment: Even I thought of worksheet formula but then this is what OP had to say `The amount of data rows will change` ;)

Comment: Thanks everyone for your effort this helps

Answer (score 0):

is vba required?

if not, the function `=COUNTIF(C:C,">45")` will give you the answer you want.